# Determining and proving supremum and infimum of given set.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $ A\subset\mathbb{R} $ a bounded set, $ \mathbb{N} = \{0,1,2,...\} $ and 
$$ B:= \left\{\frac{n}{n+1} - a \mid a \in A, n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$$
Give inf B and sup B in terms of  inf A and sup A. Also prove these statements.

So I thought $\sup B = 1 - \inf A.$

Proof for this: $\dfrac{n}{n+1}$ is bounded from above by 1 and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \dfrac{n}{n+1}=1.$

Further $\forall a\in A: -1+a\geq-1+\inf A$, so $\forall a\in A: 1-a\leq1-\inf A$. So $\sup B = 1 - inf A$.

For $\inf B$, I thought $\inf B = - \sup A$.

Proof for this: $\dfrac{n}{n+1}\geq0$ $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. $\forall a\in A:a\leq \sup A$, so $\forall a\in A:-a\geq -\sup A$. So $\inf B = 1 - \sup A$.

Can anyone tell me how formally correct this proof is and what I should improve in this proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof looks correct, but I might show the intermediate step like this:

Let $C=\left\{\frac{n}{n+1} \;\Big\vert\; n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$ so that
$$B = \left\{c-a \mid c \in C, a \in A\right\}.$$  Now,
$$\sup B = \sup C - \inf A = 1 - \inf A, $$
and
$$\inf B = \inf C - \sup A = 0 - \sup A. $$
Ensure you prove what $\sup C$ and $\inf C$ are correctly and you should be done.  (In this case $\inf C=\min C$, so that's easy.  $\sup C$ takes only a little bit of effort.)